# Double click .jar file to launch it in command line

Tags: java, user-interface, command-line, jar

I'm trying to make one of my command line utilities a little more user friendly.  Most of my co-workers don't mind using the utility as a CLI, but navigating to it is a bit of a pain (to them).  I'd rather not go to every computer and set up a shortcut in their CLI so:

Is there a way to make a .jar file launch a command line utility into a command prompt (preferably PowerShell?)  I tried searching Google and Stack Overflow but am having a hard time making headway...  Any direction would be much appreciated.

I somehow imagine this using `Desktop`, but am not sure how that would work.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Maybe you need to make a swing based console to redirect output and input. Here are the links I found in a simple web search. (I've never used these before)

- [Message Console](http://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/08/message-console/)
- [Simple Java Console](http://www.comweb.nl/java/Console/Console.html)

And an open source project here at [Swing-Console](https://github.com/mikera/swing-console).

***EDIT:***

Another option. What if you distribute your application with a `run-me.bat` file?

```
@echo off
java -jar my-console-app.jar
```

You can also change the title.

Comment: This is certainly an option, but I was hoping to avoid having to create a GUI for the expressed purpose of making a CLI app more attainable.  Writing a new console to recreate a console everyone already has seems a waste of time.

Comment: @JayCarr Added another option. Maybe you'll try it now.

Comment: Another good possibility.  Though, after talking with my co-workers, it seems I'm going to be exploring the first option that you listed above.  Who knew a CLI could be so intimidating?  I guess we learn something new everyday :).

Answer (score 0):

You should reassociate jar files with java.exe instead of javaw.exe. javaw is the non-CLI version of Java, but launching it with java.exe instead should do the trick.

This is how to do that(provided you have administrative rights):

```
assoc .jar=jarfileterm
ftype jarfileterm="PATH\TO\JRE\bin\java.exe" -jar "%1" %*
```

Of course, replace PATH\TO\JRE with the correct path.
After doing this, double-clicking a .jar file should open a CLI.

Comment: I've seen this approach around but I'm hesitant to do it because it looks like it would mean going to every single computer in my department and doing this.  Perhaps I misunderstand how this is implemented?

Comment: You could also just include a .bat file, which runs the jar file like this: `java -jar <jarfile>`. That would open a command-line window and execute the jar file, redirecting output to said "terminal".

Answer (score 0):

You have at least two options.

**Make an executable jar file.**

An example on Windows would look something like this:

```
mkdir temp
cd temp

for %f in (..\dist\lib\*.jar) do @jar xf %f

jar xf ..\dist\YourJar.jar 

jar cfe YourJar.jar com.something.Main *.*
```

You can read more about the jar archive tool here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/tooldocs/windows/jar.html

This is a lot easier with Maven.  See the Maven shade plug-in here: https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-shade-plugin/

**Make a Java Web Start application**

For an overview, take a look at this:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/webstart/

For a step by step guide, take a look at this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/javaws/developersguide/contents.html